# Banner on different pages have different heights

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is the result](https://www.dcsit.co.uk)
It is not meant to look like this the banner is not displayed anywhere on the website fully, some pages only displays half of the banner.

I need to work out why I don't see the banner on any of my pages, I'm trying everything.

I have a sticky banner on all but one page it doesn't work.

Now I've been going through every bit of code and I've found no joy.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 100;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p><img src="https://www.dcsit.co.uk/Assets/Banner3.png" width="100%" height="200" alt="Banner" /></p>
  <p>Contact us 07 |<a href=""> Email us</a></p>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="About.html">About</a>
  <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="Computer.html">Computer</a>
  <a href="Website.html">Website</a>
  <a href="Phone.html">Phone</a> &copy;DCSIT 2022
</div>
<hr/>
<div style="height:1000px">Content</div>
```

Comment: Are they missing or different height? Your title does not match the description. Please click F12 and look in the network console to see if the browser is looking in the correct place

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS to make a [mcve]

Comment: could you provide us with the folder structure. Maybe there is only a `../` missing (for example `../Assets/Banner3.png`).

Comment: The placing of the image is not the problem, it is where the banner is, it cannot be seen properly on pages of the website and the sticky nav bar only works on the home page and not on any of the others.

Comment: You're page is designed using tables. Who does that anno 2020? And you say that you can make people's home pages? Just resize your browser window, and you will see that the banner pops into place on smaller screeens.

Comment: I didn't ask for criticism of my methods, I know it works ok on devices but it not working well on a laptop

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="Assets/Banner3.png" width="100%" height="200" alt="Banner"/>
```

It looks good, but you can try to add slash and be sure that this source is correct. Capital letters matter

```
<img src="/Assets/Banner3.png" width="100%" height="200" alt="Banner"/>
```

Comment: The issue isn't the image that's fine, it's the way it is displayed, you can't see it properly on all the pages and the sticky navbar does not work on any of the pages except for the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: flex` from your `body` element. That messes up the entire design, pushing the banner above the top of the page on higher resolutions, because you have `align-items: center` on the `body` element as well.

Comment: I don't have them in my body elements I have them here.

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;

in the navbar a element

Comment: Doesn't matter where you have them, when it's the _whole page_ that is off-centered. Just remove the `display: flex` and you will see it for yourself.